# How to listen to email replies in c# on a server

Tags: email

We're trying to make a service that responds to email replies.
(Similar to "Reply to this email to unsubscribe" services)

**How do we listen for replies on a specified email address?**

Do we need to install an entire mail server?

Is there some simple component we can use?
or a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an email server already setup for the domain, you can just piggy back on that.  Setup an account for the email address that can receive email and then use IMAP or POP to read the emails and do the work.

You'll have to find a component to do IMAP or POP, but there are plenty out there:

- https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail
- http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/
- https://github.com/smiley22/S22.Imap
- http://www.limilabs.com/mail

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually we don't have an email server. We use AWS for sending & GoDaddy for receiving. Do you know of anyway to do this without having to have a full blown email server? Can I have an email server handle one email address without disrupting receiving at GoDaddy?

Comment: ahh - I think I can write a service to poll my POP account using these components you suggest - I see. got it - thx!